# Raphael Sequential Animation

Tags: javascript, animation, raphael

I have the following code that produces a spot that bounces from left to right and back again repeatedly. When I click the stop it stops when moving from left to right but does not stop when moving from right to left. Is there a better way to do this?

```
var paper = Raphael(10, 50, 320, 200);
var circle = paper.circle(50, 100, 20);
circle.attr("fill", "#f00");
circle.attr("stroke", "#fff");

var captured = false;
anim = Raphael.animation({cx: 270, cy: 100},2000,'ease-in-out',function(){
    this.animate({cx: 50, cy: 100},2000,'ease-in-out', function(){
        circle.animate(anim);
    });
});

circle.animate(anim);

circle.mouseover(function(){
    circle.attr("fill", "#0f0");
});

circle.mouseout(function(){
    if (captured){
        circle.attr("fill", "#00f");
    } else {
        circle.attr("fill", "#f00");
    }
})

circle.mousedown(function(){
    captured = true;
    circle.attr("fill", "#00f");
    circle.stop(anim);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could break it into 2 animations, that way you can stop them both. It depends if this is part of a more complex problem. For example...

**Callback method with 2 animations**.

```
animBack =  Raphael.animation({cx: 50, cy: 100},2000,'ease-in-out', function(){
        circle.animate(animTo);
    });
animTo = Raphael.animation({cx: 270, cy: 100},2000,'ease-in-out',function(){
        circle.animate(animBack);
    });

circle.animate(animTo);

...later 

    circle.stop(animTo);
    circle.stop(animBack);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j28b9vyf/2/)

Because there's always more than one way to do it, here is a slightly odder way that maybe makes more sense, but 'feels' more complex initially! I'm including it, as it may give some interesting workarounds for people.

**Custom Easing Method (may seem strange, but worth a look)**

Suppose we try and actually make this into one animation. To do that, we could create our custom easing that makes the ball bounce to AND from in one easing. We can modify one of Raphaels ease-in-out methods and split the animation time by 2....Raphael has an easing_formulas hash we can extend.

Lets create a new easing formula, which will go all the way there, and all the way back in one go.

```
Raphael.easing_formulas["easeInOutReturn"] = function(n) {
        if( n > 0.5 ) { n = (1 - n)*2  }
        else { n = n * 2 };
        var q = .48 - n / 1.04,
            Q = Math.sqrt(.1734 + q * q),
            x = Q - q,
            X = Math.pow(Math.abs(x), 1 / 3) * (x < 0 ? -1 : 1),
            y = -Q - q,
            Y = Math.pow(Math.abs(y), 1 / 3) * (y < 0 ? -1 : 1),
            t = X + Y + .5;
        return (1 - t) * 3 * t * t + t * t * t;
};
```

Note, the if/then line which is missing in the original easing formula. We split the time up and animate there for first half, and back for the 2nd half of the easing (as easing is just an interpolation of values from 0->1 depending on current time passed). Then we use our custom easing, and we can use a single stop.

```
anim = Raphael.animation({cx: 270, cy: 100},4000,'easeInOutReturn')
              .repeat(Infinity);

...
circle.stop(anim);
```

[jsfiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/j28b9vyf/8/)